# React App - My alert window is showing up twice

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I don't understand why this is happening - I have an app that increments and decrements a counter when the buttons are pressed to display an increasing list of easter egg brands from a collection. When the counter reaches the max number of eggs in the collection I want a popup to appear saying "Limit has been reached". The popup appears, but when I click okay, the same popup shows up again!

Is the React component being called twice somewhere?

If anyone has any ideas, this would be much appreciated.

**App.js**

```
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import Counter from './Counter';
    import EggList from './EggList';
    import './App.css';
    
    function App() {
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Counter></Counter>      
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

**Counter.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import EggList from './EggList';
    
    class Counter extends React.Component {
    
      constructor(props) {
        super(props) 
        this.state = { 
          counter: 0
        }
    
        this.increment = this.increment.bind(this)
        this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this) 
    
      }
    
      increment(){
        this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 })
      };
    
      decrement(){
        this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter - 1 })
      };
      
      render() {
        const { counter } = this.state;
        var eggsArray = [
            'Lindt',
            'Creme Egg',
            'Oreo',
            'Cadburys',
            'Mars',
            'Aero'
          ];
        return (
          <div>
            <h1 id="counter">{counter}</h1>
            <button type="button" id="decrement" onClick={this.decrement}>Decrement</button>
            <button type="button" id="increment" onClick={this.increment}>Increment</button>
            <EggList eggs={eggsArray} counter={counter}></EggList>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    
    export default Counter;
```

**Egglist.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    
    class EggList extends React.Component {
        render(){
            var eggs = [];
            var upperlimit = false;
            if(this.props.counter < 0){
                window.alert("Warning: Counter cannot be less than zero");
                
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < this.props.counter; i++){
                console.log("Counter: " + this.props.counter);
                console.log("Total eggs: " + this.props.eggs.length);
                if(this.props.counter > this.props.eggs.length){
                    upperlimit = true;
                    break;
                }                    
                eggs.push(<li key={i.toString()}>{this.props.eggs[i]}</li>);
            }
            if(upperlimit === true){
                console.log('upperlimit');
                window.alert("Warning: Counter exceeds number of eggs");
                
            }
           
        
        
            return (
    
    
                <ul className="egg-list">
                    {eggs}
                </ul>
            )
       } 
    }
    
    export default EggList;
```

Thanks,

Robert

London, UK

Comment: Looks like the "render" function is called twice in your case . 
Check out react component lifecycle hooks and move "alert" call on proper callback .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does your index.js have the tag strict mode?
If that's the case, remove it and try again.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Try with this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Glad it worked! the reason is that strict mode renders components twice on development to detect errors in your code.

Comment: I use older react version that this and doesn't have React.StrictMode, is there other way for older versions? thank you

Comment: This seems like a workaround. Is there a 'correct' way to use `window.alert()` in React StrictMode such that it doesn't appear twice in development mode?

Comment: 2023 and I'm looking for this answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Remove strict mode

````
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);```
````